# Pyinstaller with fastapi and database

Tags: pyinstaller, fastapi

[image: folder structure]

This is folder structure of my fastapi app. I am using sqlalchemy to connect to Postgres database. I am using uvicorn server.

In my main.py:

```
functions.models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
tasks.models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
app= FastAPI()
app.include_router(functions.main.router)
app.include_router(tasks.main.router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(f"{Path(__file__).stem}:app", host='0.0.0.0', port=8127, workers=1)
```

I am trying to compile into exe with pyinstaller. This is my spec file, please advice what is wrong that main doesn't load:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['...\\app'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['uvicorn.lifespan.off','uvicorn.lifespan.on','uvicorn.lifespan',
             'uvicorn.protocols.websockets.auto','uvicorn.protocols.websockets.wsproto_impl',
             'uvicorn.protocols.websockets_impl','uvicorn.protocols.http.auto',
             'uvicorn.protocols.http.h11_impl','uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl',
             'uvicorn.protocols.websockets','uvicorn.protocols.http','uvicorn.protocols',
             'uvicorn.loops.auto','uvicorn.loops.asyncio','uvicorn.loops.uvloop','uvicorn.loops',
             'uvicorn.logging','app.database'],
             hookspath=['extra-hooks'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is simply a problem with the current directory where PyInstaller is built. If the current directory where PyInstaller is built is always the same, you may want to use the following statement in your spec file.

```py
import os

current_dir = os.getcwd()
work_dir = current_dir
source_dir = current_dir +'\\app\\(your source folder)'
sub_path_list = [
   '\\(required path)',
   ...
]
pathex_list = [source_dir,t_dir] + [ source_dir+add_path for add_path in sub_path_list]
print(pathex_list)

a = Analysis([source_dir +'\\main.py'],
             pathex=pathex_list,
...(omit)
```